# Flash - In right click context menu mouse cursor not visible when using a custom cursor

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm using Flash actionscript2.0 and I'm using this code to show a custom cursor.

`onEnterFrame = function()

{

    Mouse.hide();

    myCursor._x = _xmouse;

    myCursor._y = _ymouse;

}`

But this results in disappearing mouse cursor when viewing right click context menu.
Is there a way to show the standard mouse cursor when viewing the context menu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tap into the [onSelect event of the ContextMenu object](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001554.html#wp209017) to show the cursor when the user goes to use the menu. Getting the cursor to show again may be a bit more tricky, but you may be able to do it by swapping in a movieclip above everything else that looks for mouse overs or mouse moves. I don't think it will get any events while the menu is up but should once the menu goes away.